# Sanskrit shloka of Padma Purana Srsti-khanda 19.336

Tags: identification-request, padma-purana

I'd like to know the Sanskrit shloka of Padma Purana Srsti-khanda 19.336. Here is the English translation; "Listen to the essence of dharma, and after listening, put it into practice: Do not perform acts towards others that you find displeasing to yourself.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English version cited, consists of the second half of verse 335 and first half of verse 336 of [Chapter 19](https://archive.org/details/ThePadmaPuranaPart1NagPublishers/page/n235/mode/2up) of the Padma Purana Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa. The verses go as follows:

> श्रूयतां धर्मसर्वस्वं श्रुत्वा चैतत्प्रधार्यताम् ॥- 19.335 second half
> आत्मनः प्रतिकूलानि परेषां न समाचरेत्। - 19.336 first half
>
> Listen to the all-in-all of righteousness; retain it after having heard it. (Second half of 19.335) Do not do to others what is unfavourable to yourself. (First half of 19.336)

Comment: Dear Archit, thank you so much for giving me a merciful answer so quickly. It really helps me a lot. I'd like make sure that "19.336 first half part : आत्मनः प्रतिकूलानि परेषां न समाचरेत्।" relate to the meaning : "Do not do to others what is unfavourable to yourself" ?

Comment: "I'd like make sure that "19.336 first half part : आत्मनः प्रतिकूलानि परेषां न समाचरेत्।" relate to the meaning : "Do not do to others what is unfavourable to yourself" ?" -- yes that's correct.. @Radhikadasi

Comment: @Archit can u pls update the Sanskrit text source if u have any?

Comment: @YDS sure......

Comment: @Radhikadasi i have bifurcated the translation for ease of reference. See if it’s alright

Comment: Dear Archit, You helped me, thank you so much.

Comment: Dear YDS, thank you for your teaching. I can use this siloka for preaching.

Comment: @Radhikadasi, much obliged, you may want to accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons, if you find it worth it. So that others can know that this is an okay answer